# In MS Office Excel v1909, where is the correct place to click to unhide multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When clicking to unhide multiple columns, I start by shift left clicking on the header of leftmost visible column, then shift left clicking on the header of the rightmost visible column to select all the hidden columns between them.

However, at that point I want to right click to get the column menu that includes the "Unhide" option. However, right clicking on any column header (even with the shift key down) collapses the selection to only that column, leaving the hidden columns no longer selected. Right clicking on the cells seems to, at random, produce the column menu with the Unhide option or the cell menu which does not include this option.

Where is the correct place to right click to produce the column menu while maintaining a multiple column selection?

Comment: The answer given below is an alternate method, but your comment revealed the problem you were having and the actual answer to your question ("where should I right click to produce this behavior / why when I right click in the 'right' place I don't see expected results") as asked. I'd suggest you should write up an answer, including screenshots of what the table headers look like when the sheet is scrolled down, because that can be quite confusing in similar instances.

Answer (score 0):

You were very near to doing it:

- After selecting the columns, go to the Home tab
- Click Format in the Cells section
- In the drop-down menu, in the sub-menu Hide & Unhide, click Unhide Columns
- Done.

Comment: Ok. I did find also the problem: if a sheet contains a table and is scrolled down, Excel replaces the column headers with the table headers, but also changes the click behaviour in this way.